# What was the last 5.25-inch floppy disk drive manufactured?

Tags: floppy-disk, floppy-drive

Assuming that no manufacturer of removable-media disk-drives is still manufacturing disk-drives for *5¼-inch floppy disks* - what was the last drive model manufactured / sold and who was the manufacturer?

**Update:**

Via comments it became clear that the "last one manufacturing" isn't necessarily the last because of product quality. As an analogy for that, from the audio realm, one example would be the (Matsushita) Technics SL-1200 turntable which is a reference grade product and had a long production streak, but was finally discontinued in 2010. Despite that, over the years following, a number of manufacturers still produced and sold turntables, some being better, but most below the specs of the SL-1200.

This is where the analogy ends, as 5.25" media became obsolete and no renaissance of the format, as with vinyl, happend (well, yet). So this question's aim is to look at *who was the last to actually* (and not just relabel) 5.25-inch floppy disk drives. If someone could provide a little commentary on build quality, that would be a plus though.

Comment: I'm not voting to close but this seems like two questions. You're asking for the factual last drive made but also the opinion of the best drive to buy today.  Based on other dying formats the last manufacturer left was the one who kept cutting costs the longest. As an example the last cassette tape player mechanism has long been Tanashin but they sound terrible compared most of the used 80s Pioneer/Sony/Technics stuff you can still find on ebay. Maybe you should clarify which question you want answered.

Comment: Fascinating. I decided to see if anyone actually does still make 5.25s, since there are certainly plenty of 3.5s. I found one on Amazon, with one vendor claiming new (which is possible if it sat in a box for 30 years - stranger things have happened). https://amzn.to/3N4FMkQ $ 350 - $ 500! I guess if you really need a 5.25 drive for the nuclear missile launch codes (I've heard they use 8") or whatever, $ 500 is worth it.

Comment: Do you got any proof they are no longer manufactured? After all, if there's a market, there's a supply. Also, asking for what to buy isn't exactly on topic here.

Comment: With a username like _Micropolis_, it seems that **you** should be an expert on 5.25" drives!

Comment: if it has a pressed steel chassis, run away! I came across a few bad 8" disk drives (Tandon TM800) but very few 5 1/4" back in the day.

Comment: The [SL-1200](https://www.technics.com/global/home/sl1200/heritage.html) is back in production, unlike 5¼" drives